# Why can't install Guest Additions on VirtualBox for Debian OS?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, guest-additions

VirtualBox version

6.1

[virtualbox version pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV8tW.png)

Installed Debian 10.4.0 on it.

From VirtualBox menu select **Devices** -> **Insert Guest Additions CD Image**. CD automatically ran but unable to locate the program. Why?

[guest additions folder in virtualbox pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwNFI.png)

[will run application on debian pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqx42.png)

[cause an alert can't install the program pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JfSr.png)

---

**Addition**

After ran this by `root` user, it can be installed

```
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

But there is an another problem, restart OS it shown:

```
VBoxClient: The parent session seems to be non-X11. Exiting...
```

[select default GNOME on the login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77UBN.png)

[VBoxClient alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2opP.png)

If resize the window to full screen, it can't change size at all.

Comment: I haven't had that problem in some time (not sure why) but I used to have to mount the tools drive, copy the files from it to my home, extract as needed, mark as executable, and run with `sudo dpkg -i `, or I think they have some shell scripts you can run. good luck.

Comment: I found I can't run `sudo` with my user in the system. The problem maybe is also due to the file or folder permission.

Comment: well, and it installs kernel drivers so root is definitely required. if you don;t have sudo, can you `su root`?

Comment: Oh, you saved me! I can run `su root`, and then I ran `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to install the program successfully!

Comment: But if I run `sh sudo`, it said `su: user sudo does not exist`. It seems `sudo` user doesn't exist after I install the OS.

Comment: @FrankThomas I got another problem. Added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: This should walk you through the process. it looks like they use the --nox11 switch on the .run invocation.  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-debian-10/ and for sudo see here: https://www.osradar.com/how-to-enable-sudo-on-debian-10/

Comment: Thank you! All works well now. If you can write it down as an answer, I will adopt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your update:

```
VBoxClient: The parent session seems to be non-X11. Exiting...
```

Following the suggestion in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/gkq3iz/why_cant_install_guest_additions_on_virtualbox/frbjpmh/), it seems a bug in VirtualBox Guest Additions 6.1.

The last Guest Additions from 6.0 (http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.22/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.22.iso) should not be affected.

I can confirm the old Additions work on my setup:

- Windows 10 host
- Debian Stretch guest
- VirtualBox 6.1.8
- Guest Additions 6.0.22